# Dynamically assign at class creation a dynamically created metaclass

Tags: python, metaclass

I believe the question sounds a bit confusing, so I'll give more details in the following.

I have these two classes define, one of which inherits `type`:

```
class ProductType(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        return super(ProductType, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class Product(object):
    __metaclass__ = ProductType
```

Now, at runtime, I create a subclass of `ProductType`:

```
Insurance = type('Insurance', (ProductType,), {})
```

And then, create a subclass of `Product`, which will have it's metaclass set as `Insurance`:

```
HouseInsurance = type('HouseInsurance', (Product,), {'__metaclass__': Insurance})
```

Now, for some obvious reason (which I don't seem to see by now), if I do `type(HouseInsurance)` I get `ProductType`, not `Insurance`. It seems that the dynamically created class ignores the given dynamically created metaclass for some reason. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, use

```
>>> HouseInsurance = Insurance('HouseInsurance', (Product,), {})
>>> type(HouseInsurance)
__main__.Insurance
```

`__metaclass__` is a way for a programmer to express the constructor of a class object at file parsing time, as opposed to runtime.

Comment: Oh, I knew it would be something simple. Thank you for pointing this out!